# Best way to fetch metaplex token metadata

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, token, metadata

In a NextJS app. Say I enable a user to created a basic token using the `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` library with some metadata like name, symbol, decimal, uri etc... And I also enable the user to create an associated account for this mint. How do I now fetch the metadata when I display this account to the user?

Right now I am using `getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner` from the `@solana/web3` library to fetch all the users token accounts, and this does in fact fetch all the users token accounts including the ones created with metaplex but nowhere in the data structure does it have the metadata details.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` already you can just use one of the fetch functions this package provides https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch

Since you are referring to showing the user a token that they minted something like this might be relevant to you

```
import { fetchDigitalAssetWithAssociatedToken } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const asset = await fetchDigitalAssetWithAssociatedToken(umi, mint, owner)
```